# How to make POST request using OAuth via Youtube API?

Tags: http, post, youtube-api, request, google-oauth

I am trying to get this thing to work for a couple days since it's my first time working with the OAuth system without any luck.

I have been experimenting here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#try-it

With the following settings:
http://i.gyazo.com/5cd28f1194d5dfebee25d07bc0db965e.png

When I execute the code it successfully subscribes to the specified `channelId`account with the authorized account.

I have tried to copy paste the shown POST URL into my browser without any luck. The plan was just to test it as I would like to implement this in PHP.

Now to my questions:

1. The `{YOUR_API_KEY}`, is this where I am supposed to type in the access token? If so, do I need the `&mine=true` tag at all?
2. I just realized that there are no ID's in the URL but there is an JSON-object in the request box example. Am I supposed to convert a string to JSON-object and pass it to the `$fields=` tag?

Comment: The API key is not the same as a token; the API key authenticates your app when you're getting public data that doesn't need user permission. An oAuth2 token is used when you do need user permission. The request needs an access token sent in the header (or as a URL parameter) ... the API explorer works because, when you authenticate with the button, the app gets the access token and sends it in its headers. You'll want to start here to understand oAuth: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication -- note that it requires a user manually click to authorize your app.

Comment: Hey, I understand that and I have everything ready in my app (access tokens, refresh tokens) are already saved in a database and handled. I am trying to setup the last part where user X can subscribeto user Y, do you have any idea how I could setup that since I have no idea how to complete this as a URL parameter that you pointed out?

Comment: You can either pass it on the URL with access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN} or put it in a header value: Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN} ... see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API for more details.

Comment: Alright, let's say that I pass the access_token instead of the api key in the URL, how do I handle the snippet json object that contains the channel id? I am trying to do this via the URL since I have no idea how the header part works...